# updating PostgreSQL database index in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have added the following to my model in order to activate indexing for my data in database:

```
class Meta:

    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['symbol', 'interval', '-date_time']),
    ]
```

when migrating, it takes a while to index, which is fine. My question is that when adding new data, how should I update the index again? would it get indexed automatically or I need to run something?

Thanks

Comment: All existing indexes on a table will be updated every time any row(s) are updated/deleted/added. You do not need to do anything

Comment: Thanks, please add this as response then I would select it as answer. Thanks for prompt reply.